# Using high filter functions and recursion

Tags: haskell, recursion, functional-programming

I need to code 2 functions in Haskell **but** with 2 differents methods each (high-filter and recursion).

I have 2 tuples to do this:

> **Material** is `(Model, Price, Accesories) :: (String, Int, [(String, Int)])`
>
> **Accesory** is `(Name, Price) :: (String, Int)`

- The first function `totalPrice` receives the Material tuple and has
  to return the total price (Material price + Accesories price)

  Example:

  > Main> totalPrice ("Table",150,[("Chair",100),("Chair",5)])
  >
  > Returns: totalPrice = 255

  I already made it with recursion:

  ```
  totalPrice (_,x,l) = x + sum l
  sum [] = 0
  sum (t:ts) = snd t + sum ts
  ```

  but I don't know how to do it with high-filter functions.
- The second function **expensiveMaterialsPrice** receives a list of
  Materials and has to return only the sum of the total prices of the
  expensive materials. A

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need a filter for `totalPrice` at all, I think you're looking for the term "higher order function".  Instead, you just need a function to access the price of an accessory:

```
accessoryPrice :: (String, Int) -> Int
accessoryPrice (_, price) = price
```

Then you can easily transform a list of accessories into a list of prices:

```
accessoryPrices :: [(String, Int)] -> [Int]
accessoryPrices accessories = map accessoryPrice accessories
```

Now you can use sum on the output of this to get the total accessory price

```
totalAccessoryPrice :: [(String, Int)] -> Int
totalAccessoryPrice accessories = sum $ accessoryPrices accessories
```

And I'll leave it to you to integrate this into your current code =)

---

Fun fact, `accessoryPrice` is just a more specific form of `snd`, and you could instead write this code in the much shorter form

```
totalAccessoryPrice = sum . map snd
```

But this is far less clear as to your intentions.  I would *highly* recommend using the more verbose form for now, it helps to break the problem into discrete steps to solve instead of trying to tackle the entire solution at once.

---

For the `expensiveMaterialsPrice`, you will want to use a filter.  In this case, you should make a function `isExpensive :: (String, Int, [(String, Int)]) -> Bool` to indicate if a material is expensive or not:

```
isExpensive :: (String, Int, [(String, Int)]) -> Bool
isExpensive material = totalPrice material > 1500
```

Then you can use `isExpensive` as the predicate (the first argument) to `filter`.

---

Something that might help would be to create some type aliases:

```
type Name = String
type Price = Int
type Accessory = (Name, Price)
type Material = (Name, Price, [Accessory])

accessoryPrice :: Accessory -> Price
-- same definition

accessoryPrices :: [Accessory] -> [Price]
-- same definition

totalAccessoryPrice :: [Accessory] -> Price
-- same definition

totalPrice :: Material -> Price
-- your definition here

isExpensive :: Material -> Bool
-- same definition
```

It doesn't change the meaning of your code at all, aliases are interchangeable (i.e. `Price` and `Int` are the same type, just with different names), but it does reduce typing and makes your intentions very clear.

Comment: For function expensiveMaterialsPrice using recursion, can I do something like

> expensiveMaterialsPrice materials | isExpensive material == True = totalPrice material + expensiveMaterialsPrice materials

Got stuck here now, thanks for all the help.

Comment: If you want to use explicit recursion instead of filter, you have to specify both cases, i.e. if it is expensive or if it isn't.  Using an if-statement (because it's easier to format in a comment, same result as using guards): `expensiveMaterialsPrice [] = 0`; `expensiveMaterialsPrice (m:ms) = if isExpensive m then totalPrice m + expensiveMaterialsPrice ms else expensiveMaterialsPrice`.  You have to give the base case of when your list of materials is empty (the price is `0`), and then you can use pattern matching to pull the first element off the list with `(m:ms)`.

Comment: If you instead wanted to use `filter`, it'd be much shorter: `expensiveMaterialsPrice materials = sum $ map totalPrice $ filter isExpensive materials`, and only one line.  You can even write it in the "point free" form (google it, there are good explanations out there) `expensiveMaterialsPrice = sum . map totalPrice . filter isExpensive`.

Answer (score 0):

`totalPrice` implemented by using higher-order function:

```
totalPrice (_,x,l) = x + (sum $ map snd l)
```

and `expensiveMaterialsPrice`

```
expensiveMaterialsPrice ms = sum $ map totalPrice $ filter isExpensive ms
    where isExpensive m = totalPrice m > 1500
```

Comment: `x + sum $ map snd l` won't work, you'll get a compile error because of the `$`.